# Apache2 - Resolving redirect to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Even after trying several solutions, I'm trying to force HTTPS redirect on my website via the following configuration in the site's .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, it's resulting in the error of too many redirects. I came to suspect this may be either because of the the HTTPS flag not being set or port number not switching to 443 on specifying https in the browser - as on outputting the port number via PHP, i.e, $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] it still shows 80. My .conf files were set up according to what I came across on what seemed to be reliable sources.

Any insights into how I can get this resolved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apache foundation suggests to [avoid](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) using mod_rewrite for this type of problem when possible.

You should use [mod_alias **Redirect** directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com
# ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

---

However, in cases where You are limited to .htaccess only and cannot alter vhost/main configuration files, You can do this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```